# Non transparent div inside a transparent div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage that have a transparent div.

I want to add a non-transparent div inside that transparent div and I find that it is also transparent.

I try to set the div inside to opacity:1 but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the code?

Comment: I'm really curious why you'd need to do this. The background of the div is transparent by default.  Why make the whole thing transparent just to show it again?

Comment: The issue comes into play if you color a div, and set its opacity to make it transparent. If you then want to put text on this div, the text is transparent, and that isn't always desirable.

Comment: Again ... why set a background color just to make it transparent?

Comment: i think when he says transparent he isnt talking about 0 opacity. in which case his situation is perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two ways that I know of to work around this:

- Fake transparency on the containing div by using a transparent PNG as the background image.
- Separate the divs so that they are side-by-side, and then use relative or absolute positioning to stack them.

Comment: Well, by using a parent element with position:relative, you can also have an absolutely-positioned, translucent child element positioned behind normally-positioned, non-translucent child elements. This has the advantage of not needing external images or fixed sizes.

Comment: Depending on your situation you should consider, that IE6 does not support transparent PNGs by itself and needs some help (with additional javascript libraries).

Comment: Might be mute, since IE6 & 7 don't support the CSS opacity that billy is using anyway (unless of course he didn't mention his IE alpha filter).

Comment: There is a workaround for transparent PNGs on IE6 by using a little css. http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Comment: @NilObject: but in that case, you'd probably be better off just using a filter to fake opacity.

Comment: But then you must mess around with positioning, which may not be preferred. Since my answer gives to valid approaches, I was just pointing out that if you wanted to go with the transparent PNG approach, you can make it work.

Comment: Actually... You can use IE's gradient filter (with both starting and ending colors identical, and an appropriate alpha value for each) to fake background transparency without any positioning worries or a background image.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right, I misunderstood what you meant in your previous comment. I haven't experimented enough with filters in IE enough to say for sure, so I'll trust that you're right.

Answer (score 45):

I found this somewhere while researching CSS3 and apologize that I cannot re-call where so as to credit the appropriate author.

But if you are looking for a semi-transparent background solid color on a div. Instead of setting the color and controlling transparency with opacity/alpha properties, set the background-color property directly using rgba(rrr,ggg,bbb,aaa) format. This will prevent any child elements from inheriting any transparency.

ex.

```
#mydiv { background-color: rgba(128,64,0,0.75); }
```

Comment: Great answer, this should have the green tick.

Comment: Great solution! There are a lot of sites out there saying there is no solution for this problem!

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8 and down but that's because IE8 and down doesn't support RGBa transparency. You can set a fall back color though like this found on CSS-tricks http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

div {
   background: rgb(200, 54, 54); /* The Fallback */
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); 
}

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work in CSS unfortunately. In the past I've used positioning to push the non transparent div containing the content into the transparent div. I couldn't dig up some old code from my projects, but I did find this blog post:

[Non-transparent elements inside transparent elements](http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

use background, padding, background-origin to control the padding and z-index to control the position of the element. For example:

```
#mydiv{ background: white; padding:100px; background-origin:border-box; z-index:1}
```