# z-index problem in IE with transparent div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I have a transparent div-element with a higher z-index than an img-element on the same page. But Internet Explorer is acting as if the img-element would have a higher z-value when it comes to click events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <img src="7player.png" alt="7player" width="60" height="60" style="position:absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; z-index:10" />
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;z-index:900;" onclick="alert('hello');"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the image nothing happens altough the click event of the div-element should be fired (works in Chrome for example).

Is there any workaround or fix for my problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In fact, your div "Doesn't have any background",

You need to give it a color background (e.g. white) with opacity=0.01.

For example:

```
 background:white; filter:alpha(opacity=1);
```

Comment: _background:transparent_ has no effect, but using a color with an alpha filter does work thanks for the suggestion: _background:white;filter:alpha(opacity=1);_

_height=100%_ works perfectly.

Comment: Check this answer out - setting background with rgba makes it clickable too - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6780462/273488

Comment: @ryan: Internet Explorer 8,7,6,... don't support rgba, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: FYI to target this to IE 8 only use following hack: `background: white\9; filter:alpha(opacity=1)\9;`

Comment: Now that it is the end of 2014, and the standards people are rewriting filters with a completely different syntax (not yet supported by IE), I'm going with the transparent image solution so I do not have problems with future filter syntax issues.

Answer (score 4):

Using a transparent image seems like a reasonable work-around for IE.  This was answered already here:

[IE z-index trouble on element with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109911/ie-z-index-trouble-on-element-with-transparent-background)

Comment: Actually, this thread here is older, so it was not already answered ;)
Still ... the trick with the transparent image is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the Suggestion given by Preli `background:white;filter:alpha(opacity=1)`, and it is working fine. See the Demo in IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/VMrNF/11/

Comment: In fact this was given by me ;)

Comment: That's right - the idea came from valipour - the code is mine. Perfect teamwork ;) 
Too bad that it needs such an (in my opinion) ugly workaround to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a bug in IE11, but not Edge. The following solved my problem by creating a background that "looks" transparent but has a color.

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
```

Slightly better that the filter solution above, if you want only the background to be transparent, but not the contents of the object.

Answer (score 0):

add left:0 to div, click event available

tested in ie9