# IE z-index trouble on element with transparent background

Tags: css, internet-explorer, textarea, z-index

everyone.
I need 2 absolutely positioned textarea elements to be placed one over the other.
Here is my sample:

```
<div>
  <textarea id="txt1" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;z-index:0;background:none;">some text</textarea>
  <textarea id="txt2" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;z-index:1;background:none;"></textarea>
</div>
```

I'm expecting txt1 to be under the txt2. That happens in FF and Chrome. But in IE (tested in 8 and 9) txt1 is clickable and becomes focus.

Does anybody know, how to manage this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try it by putting both textarea in separate div

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not play well with "empty" elements. By making the `background: none` and having no content, IE treats the top `textarea` as if it was not there.

To get around this, you can use a transparent png for the background instead:

```
background: url(/images/transparent.png) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Gkd/**

#### Edit

As suggested by @Ryan, you can use data URI to add a transaparent gif to the background, meaning you do not need to create an actual transparent png:

```
background: transparent 0 0 repeat scroll url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBR‌​AA7");
```

Another solution, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480792/681807), is to add a coloured background with full opacity:

```
background:white; filter:alpha(opacity=1);
```

Comment: @Michael No problem - I have been there with IE, so I know most of it flaws by now :) Don't forget to accept the answer so others know that it is a working solution

Comment: Tip: you can use a a data URI with a 1px by 1px transparent gif repeated as far back as IE 8.  The rule would look like: background: transparent 0 0 repeat scroll url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");

Comment: @Ryan beautiful. It should included in the answer.

Comment: Now that it is the end of 2014, and the standards people are rewriting filters with a completely different syntax (not yet supported by IE), I'm going with the transparent image solution so I do not have problems with future filter syntax.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very interesting bug that I've never encountered before.  IE acts like the block on top isn't even there since it's not rendered visibly.

It strikes me as odd that it works in FF / Webkit because `none` would be a setting for the `background-image` property.  That should work okay in the shorthand version of the property, but I think it should also leave the `background-color` set to the default (usually white).  In any case, I guess I'm wrong about this.  And setting either `background` or `background-color` to `transparent` doesn't fix the problem.

Here's a little bit of a workaround: Rather than specifying `background: none`, use `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)`.  That will give you a transparent background.  Unfortunately, it only works in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is still at IE11 emulating to ie 10. A pure css workaround I did was force a background-color and work with:

```
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.0;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; //IE8 Support
```

Of course I'm forgetting IE7.

Comment: I thought that IE 10 didn't support -ms-filter? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)