# IE10 html5 with doctype and z-index

Tags: html, z-index, internet-explorer-10, doctype

I have this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/z5BCm/
It's a div which contain 2 divs inside and one of them is a table with a specific size (500x500 for example) and high zIndex (9998) and the other div have a input text inside with low zIndex.
The question is: Why in the IE10 am i able to access the input if the table zindex cover all over it ?
It works correctly on Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari and so on..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%">
            <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 663px; height: 574px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 99998;">
                <table width="100%" height="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="left: 11px; top: 27px; width: 110px; height: 36px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
                <div style="left: 0px; top: -15px; height: 15px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"><font class="label" style="white-space: nowrap; cursor: default;" draggable="false"><strong>Login</strong><strong style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">&nbsp;*</strong></font>
                </div>
                <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 110px; height: 21px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 2;">
                    <input name="WFRInput100000005" class="edit" style="z-index:1;width: 110px; height: 21px; text-decoration: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="on">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And old question, I know, but I just ran into this myself. The issue is IE's tendency to ignore transparent elements (see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109911/ie-z-index-trouble-on-element-with-transparent-background) for more details). I was able to hack a fix on your fiddle by adding a white background color (with opacity set to 0) to the table's parent div.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5BCm/1/
Specifically, here's what changed:

```
        <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 663px; height: 574px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 99998; background-color: white; opacity:0;">
```