# IE 9 is not respecting my overlay and applying css to contained elements only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So after some digging I am not sure what the issue is here. I have a text field that is overlaid with a div. The div contains a ul with multiple li representing currently applied filters to a table. The overlay is supposed to catch the clicks to open a menu and hold any new filters.

EDIT:

To clarify the need is for IE9 specifically. For some reason the overlay is not what comes to the foreground. I can click on specifically the li and get the behavior I am expecting but there are space between and at the end that the overlay appears not to be present.

--My code--

HTML:

```
<!-- Start filter row-->
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-3 medium-2 large-1 columns">
        <span class="prefix">Current Filters:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="small-9 medium-10 large-11 columns">
        <div id="manager_filter_overlay" class="filter_overlay">
            <ul>
                <li class="filter_item">Status: Active</li>
                <li class="filter_item">Start Date: 07/MAR/2014</li>
                <li class="filter_item">End Date: 07/APR/2014</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" onkeydown="return false;" style="z-index:0;">
    </div>
    <div class="filter-menu">
        <div class="arrow-up"></div>
        <div class="filter-menu-container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>Status:
                        <select>
                            <option>
                                Active
                            </option>
                            <option>
                                Deleted
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Start Date:
                        <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MMM/YYY">
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>End Date:
                        <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MMM/YYY">
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 center columns">
                    <input type="button" class="button tiny blue" value="Search">
                    <input type="button" class="button tiny blue" value="Reset">
                    <input type="button" class="button tiny blue" value="Save">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End filter row-->
```

CSS:

```
.filter_overlay{
    position:absolute;
    height:37px;
    width:100%;
    /*border:1px solid black;*/
}
.filter_overlay:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    }

.filter_overlay ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.filter_overlay ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

All browsers except IE9 seem to be doing what I would expect. When hovering over the text box anywhere my cursor is a pointer I click and my drop down show (JS not included it is very basic and not anything I think is impacting the issue). In IE9 however when hovering only a pointer is shown when over an li and when outside of that it is able to get to the text field.

Comment: I don't understand your problem... I just tested it on Chrome and IE9 and it  stayed as a pointer the whole time, except in IE9, when I hovered over a bullet point, but that's it.

Comment: I think there is confusion. A css property of cursor: pointer is the hand with a finger. The overlay is what this is applied to so to cover up the text field. In IE9 the overlay can be clicked through. I do not want the user to be able to click in the text area they should always be clicking the overlay div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further looking into this appears to be related to the background. Without it based on the two threads below there are z-index issues. While they suggest using

```
background:white; filter:alpha(opacity=1);
```

I was not able to see an results from this.

All I did was added the background and a 1px border.

[IE z-index trouble on element with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109911/ie-z-index-trouble-on-element-with-transparent-background)

[z-index problem in IE with transparent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480774/z-index-problem-in-ie-with-transparent-div)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're talking about, but I moight, lol.

Anyway, if you want the default cursor everywhere, try this:

```
*:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

or if just over the bullet points, try:

```
li:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Hope this works :D

Comment: I will update to be a bit more specific. That is not really what I am looking for.