# IE10- transparent overlay using z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I am working on beautification of javascript `alert`.I need a transparent overlay which overlay the whole page other than the alert block,just like the origin javascript `alert`.

The html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="alert-overlay">
            <div class="alert-block"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css of the overlay:

```
.alert-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1100;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

The css of the alert block:

```
.alert-block{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: -150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index:1200;
}
```

It works in IE11,chrome and firefox,but failed in IE10-.

The overlay seems overlay nothing in IE10-,all the elements on the page are active.Strangely,if I add a `background-color:black`,it will overlay everything but the alert-block,and make the page inactive like the origin javascript `alert` except the additional background,which is not what I want.

So how can I make the transparent overlay work on IE10-?Is that a `z-index` bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 has some issues. Try giving a background with filter. Here is how you can do it-

```
background:white; filter:alpha(opacity=1);
```

Some helpful links :

[z-index problem in IE with transparent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480774/z-index-problem-in-ie-with-transparent-div)

[IE z-index trouble on element with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109911/ie-z-index-trouble-on-element-with-transparent-background)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!I need a transparent overlay so it should be `filter:alpha(opacity=0)`

Answer (score 0):

IE10 and less allow actions through elements when it's not having any backgorund or content. You must add a background to your overlay. Use a transparent one if you don't want it to be visible:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```