# Placing an Image over a div

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to place an image over a div, my div is

```
.my_box{
position: relative;
left: 200px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.7; 
}
```

and then my image is

```
.asvp{
position:relative;
left: 300px;
top: 100px;

}
```

When I do this is puts the image under the div, what do i do in order to place it over the div? I know to put the image into the div but that will but the opacity onto the image which I dont want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `z-index:1` to `.my_box` and `z-index: 10` to `.asvp`. Hard to peg without the HTML code though. If this doesn't work, please create a jsFiddle and I'll sort you out. :)

You should also use margins instead of `left` and `top`. For example, on `.asvp` remove left and top and put `margin: 100px 0 0 300px;`. As a general rule of thumb, I only use left, right, top, bottom on absolute elements.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, can you please explain to me what z-index does? Also, it doesn't work:/

Comment: Actually its worked!! Thank you for you answer, it is much appreciated!:) Could you still please explain what the z-index does? As i'll like to learn from it!

Comment: No prob! Glad I could help. I'm horrible at explaining things, but essentially, it allows you to reorder/set the order of positioned HTML elements. Here's a good explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_index

Comment: Basically, would you say the z-index works like layers in photoshop?

Answer (score -1):

why dont you give your image position:absolute; instead... that would automatically put it ontop of it

Comment: You would still need to `z-index` the DIVs, or reorder the HTML. But we don't know what order that's in. But yes, he should be using absolute position. Then `top:0;` and `left:0;` etc. - with `z-index.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of repositioning, you can keep the image inside the div without its opacity effecting its contents. If it's a solid semi-transparent background like in your example, you could use rgba value on the div like this:

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
```

This and other options here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780462/2909501